# Update Model from Database does not show newly created Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have been working on this app for a couple of weeks now, adding new tables,fields and stored procedures then updating the model from the database without incident.  I created a new stored procedure about 30 minutes ago and now when I go to the model browser and try to get the new stored procedure, it does not show in the list.  Permissions have not changed and everything uses the same user name and password.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the SP in the object explorer? Try the refresh button; Ctrl+Shift+R should also work

Comment: No, but thanks.  It is like it doesn't see it at all.  I decided to just delete and regenerate the edmx, but I still would like to know if someone has experienced it before in case it ever happens again.